# How to extract support vectors from SVM classifier in Python?

Tags: python, classification, svm, text-mining

I'm using LinearSVM from SciKit library in python to classify text data, and it works perfectly. 
My question is that is there a way to find the support vectors of my classifier model?
I think the support vectors for my data would be a list of words!

I need this because I want to find a distinguishing feature of the classifier for different text data. (How different text data are distinct)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with the support vectors. Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: @filannim thanks for your comment, let's put it this way: I have three classifiers: Naive Bayes, SVM, and Linear Regression. I use a train-set to train them. Now, I want to find the top 10 vocabularies (and the their corresponding weight) that are considered important for each classifier.

Comment: if you want to select the most discriminative features among the one you are using, then you can use RELIEF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relief_(feature_selection)). Have a look at "Feature Selection algorithms" for a general overview.

Comment: @filannim No using and selecting the right features is an issue before training. I'm looking for a list of words that each classifier considers as important! for example if the goal of classification is to assign a topic to a document, which words play the key role in this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the SVM case in scikit-learn you should be able to access the support vectors in the following way:

```
>>> # get support vectors
>>> clf.support_vectors_
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
>>> # get indices of support vectors
>>> clf.support_ 
array([0, 1]...)
>>> # get number of support vectors for each class
>>> clf.n_support_ 
array([1, 1]...)
```

[Source: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html ]